# What is the working and requirement of this code in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I downloaded a theme for a webpage. I found this piece of code in < head > of the index. I want to know what this script does and what if I remove it.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Some Text"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a pretty meaningless piece of code. Here is what it does in detail

```
addEventListener("load", function() { 
    setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); 
}, false);
```

[Adds a new event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It is a piece of code waiting for a "trigger" or a condition (this being an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) in this case) and it does something when that trigger is fired (condition is met). Since the target of the event is not specified, it's the `window` object it's would be attached to and since it's the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event it waits for here, this means it would wait until the entire page and all resources (e.g., images, scripts, CSS) belonging to it are completely loaded and rendered.

When that happens it would call [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) in order to schedule that the function `hideURLbar` is started after `0` milliseconds. Yes, that's like saying "execute it now" but this particular technique is a way to deal with old versions of Internet Explorer as sometimes the threading there could be overwhelmed and using `setTimeout` with a `0` parameter actually helps keep things managed.

```
function hideURLbar(){ 
    window.scrollTo(0,1); 
}
```

And this is what the actual `hiteURLbar` function is: [it scrolls the page 1 pixel down from the top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo). Unless there is some other JavaScript that is triggered by this, it seems pretty useless.